# Split PDF problems with Gs. GS limits?

Tags: ghostscript

I have a problem with ghostscript spliting pdf. I run in my script two times a ghostscript to split file. Im working on one file and In first time PDF is spliting corectly but the second time nothing is happening. No new file is creating.

I have a error on second time when I run ghostscript
"Unable to open the initial device, quitting."

Answer (score 1):

How are you 'splitting' the file ? If you post your script it might be easier to give you a clue about what's wrong. However the 'unable to open initial device' error means that you have tried to select a non-existent device, mistype the -sOutputFile command, or tried to write to a file/directory which is invalid for some reason.

Since you are running from a script, is it possible that you are trying to write to the same file twice ? If the file is still open then that will fail.

Comment: The problem is with large files.. How to split PDF which have 162 pages.. Dir TEMP is fulling when is working on it. I change TMPDIR,TMP and TEMP somewhere else but if I have 24 pages is working in new TMPDIR but with 162 pages PDF is not..

Comment: IN RUN on PHP exec         export TMPDIR=MY_DIR/tmp_cache_gs;export TMP=MY_DIR/tmp_cache_gs;export TEMP=MY_DIR/tmp_cache_gs gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  -sOutputFile=outXX.pdf -dFirstPage='.
    $start.' -dLastPage='.$end.' in.pdf

Comment: Whatever that is, I don't understand it... However from your answer above you seem to be saying that your temp directory is full ? If so then surely you need to use a bigger directory. The other possibility that springs to mind is that you are running concurrent Ghostscript threads, all writing to the same temp directory. If you do that it *will* fail because it will attempt to reuse the same temporary filenames. If you want to run Ghostscript (using the pdfwrite device) then you will have to specify a separate temp directory for each process).